# Photo tagging - Hovering on name to show the tagged box

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying make it so that when a tag name in the list is hovered, it should show a box right where it was tagged (like Facebook).

Here is my code:

Viewtag.php

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM image_tag ORDER BY `pic_id`";
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($qry);

if ($rs){
  do{
    echo '<li rel="'.$rs['pic_id'].'"><label>'.$rs['name'].'</label></li>';
  }while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qry));
}
?>
```

Index.php

```
.tagview
    {
      border:solid 3px #fff;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      position:absolute;
      display:none;
}

$('#taglist li').on('mouseover mouseout',function(event){
      pic_id = $(this).attr("rel");
      if (event.type == "mouseover"){
        $('#view_' + pic_id).show();
      }
      if (event.type == "mouseout"){
        $('#view_' + pic_id).hide();
      }
});

    viewlist();

    function viewlist()
    {
     $.post('viewtag.php', function(data){
            $('#taglist ol').html(data);
          });

}

<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_tag");
    $run = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if($run){
        do{
?>
            <div class="tagview" style = "top:<?php echo $top; ?>px; left:<?php echo $left; ?>px;" id="view_<?php echo $number; ?>"></div>
<?php
        }while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query));
    }
?>

<div id="taglist"> 
    <span class="tagtitle">List of Tags</span> 
        <ol> 
        </ol>
</div>
```

It is quite confusing, so I have posted what I have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

First of all pic_id is your variable then why u declared like this without `var`

```
pic_id = $(this).attr("rel");
```

made change  in this `var pic_id = $(this).attr("rel");`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wellbro.com/view_tutorial?t_cat=3&t_i=3

here is the URL for the tutorial on, "JQuery, PHP - photo tagging system"

Comment: Lol, I found you on YouTube like right after I asked this question. :D